# "Stamp" predefined images onto another image at mouse location

Tags: jquery, image, insert, onclick, location

I'm searching for a way to paste images out of a set/list of 5-10 "stamp images" on to an image onclick at the location of the mouse multiple times. It should feel like you "stamp" these "stamp images" on to the other image. So the "stamped" images should stay on the  image as long as you are clicking and the image underneath is only "cleared" when you reload the page.

I've searched a lot, but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for.
A similar technique was pasted on jsfiddle, but it "stamps" only one image and this vanishes when you click on another location in the image: http://jsfiddle.net/haFMn/304/

It would be perfect if the "overflow" of the "stamp image" would be visible even if it expands beyond the size of the image underneath, but you can only "stamp" when you clicking on the image underneath.

I hope somebody understands my problem, english isn't my first language.
Many, many thanks in advance!

### **jsfiddle code:**

```
        $(function() {
    $("#myimg").click(function(e) {
        var o = {
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        };
        $("#test").show(0).offset(o);
    });
});
```

It doesn't have to be anything like the above code found by me this is just the nearest to what I'm searching for.

**EDIT (Now it looks like this, if anyone is interested):**

[jsfiddle new version](http://jsfiddle.net/haFMn/322/)

```
$(function() {
$("#myimg").click(function(e) {
    var o = {
        left: e.pageX - 12.5,
        top: e.pageY - 12.5            
    };
    $("#test").clone().appendTo('body').show(0).offset(o);
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaked it slightly to this:

```
$(function() {
$("#myimg").click(function(e) {
    var o = {
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY            
    };
    $("#test").clone().appendTo('body').show().offset(o);
});
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ASMITH/haFMn/305/)

This what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! It is nearly perfect!

I tried it and it works fine until the 20th click, but from the 21th click ongoing the site-scrollbar appears and gets longer with every click. Do you understand this?

Is it possible, that the "stamp image" is placed at the center of the cursour? In this version it is placed at the bottom left side of the cursour.

And if not, thanks a lot anyways, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I figured out that the "stamp picture" needs the ccs-attribute "position: absolute;". So the scrollbar problem is history...
Is the centered placement at the coursor tip possible?

Comment: I'm a noob at this, but I figured it out.
Thanks a lot!